# PHP array, C# (string, class)

Tags: c#, php, arrays, dictionary

```
$this->modules = array(
        'module1' => new Module1(),
        'module2' => new Module2,
);
```

That is my PHP code, I've attempted to turn this in to C#.

```
public Dictionary<string, what> modules = new Dictionary<string, what>()
{
    { "module", new Module1() }
};
```

Where it says "string, what", I am unsure of what to put there.
Could someone help me with this problem I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to use (or create) a base class or interface shared by all your modules.**

For example, if you have:

```
public class Module1 : ModuleBase
{
    // stuff
}

public class Module2 : ModuleBase
{
    // stuff
}
```

then you would replace `what` in your example with `ModuleBase`.

Comment: You put code that is common to all the modules in the ModuleBase class, if they have no code in common then it would be empty

Comment: @StepCode As reggaeguitar said, any common code should be in the ModuleBase class. If they have common method signatures but different implementations, then you would make ModuleBase an interface. If they have no common method signatures at all, then an empty interface is your best bet (a class works too, but prevents your modules from inheriting from another class, since C# doesn't have multiple inheritance).

Comment: I'm now having a problem, I try access it like modules["module1"] but can't access any of module1's functions

Comment: @StepCode When you get the module that way C# only knows that it's a ModuleBase, so it only has the ModuleBase methods available. You'll need to cast it to the specific type to use the functions: `((Module1)modules["module1"]).MyFunction()`.